# Site performance wordpress with woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, load

I am generally looking for pointers and tips as to why my website is so slow.  is the url, I use cloud flare, which I thought would speed it up, but still it seems action game up, an loads slow. What is the best tool, and what do I need to do to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting here in stackoverflow. Developers usually use https://gtmetrix.com/ for measuring site speed since it has tips on loweringn it down as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use plugin like [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) which will help you diagnose if you have slow database queries. You can also check the Network tab in the Chrome Developer Tools to analyze speed of the requests to your server.